# Simulating multiple instances of application

Tags: c++, sockets, sfml

I am creating an c++ game with use of SFML. The game which i am trying to code should be multiplayer game. Game wont have server but multiplayer would be possible to play only on the same local network. I want to implement some sort of P2P socket severless communication between players. The question is how could i simulate two instances of the same application so i could test and program the functionality.

I was thinking of running two instances of app from clion directly but for network communication i would like to have different IP for each instance to simulate real-world scenario.

Comment: Virtual Machines or Containers perhaps ?

Comment: "Game wont have server but multiplayer would be possible to play only on the same local network ... I want to implement some sort of P2P socket severless communication between players"  As stated this is incompatible with IP networking.  With IP networking there is a listener ("server") and there is a client that connects to that listener.    You don't want to reinvent that wheel.  "how could i simulate two instances of the same application so i could test and program the functionality" just run two instances of the application?

Comment: @erik258 Got it working exactly like u suggested, thanks :)